# Can't move any character in blender even when in pose mode

Tags: animation

I am a new to blender...any way. I have followed these steps to the T and yet still when I try to move Vincent (character from blender), I cannot move any part of him. Any idea as to what I need to do? (I'm using blender 2.8)

These are the steps I have followed from blender site:
1. Put your 3D cursor in the Origin of your scene. Choose File > Link and browse the character file
2. Go to the Collections and select CH-Vincent.high. Make sure "Instance Collections" is enabled. Press Enter.
3. The Collection should appear instanced in the Viewport. Select it. Choose Object > Relations > Make Proxy...
4. In the list, select RIG-Vincent.

I followed the instruction listed above and I haven't configured anything else. Can anyone tell how I can solve this issue and get my character Vincent to move (meaning arms, legs etc.)

PS:
I have Blend rig 5 installed.
I am in pose mode when I try to move him...but can't.
I am on Blender Version 2.82
I have also tried other  (pre rigged) characters from blender cloud but none of them can move.

Answer (score 1):

after digging up in 2.82 I’ve solved it by clicking move in object gizmos (which was turned off by default)I have uploaded an image of what i am referring to for anyone who has or had this issue of the character not being able to move or pose at all. [Enable the move checkbox ☑️ in order for your move and pose your character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cgt5.jpg)